# Trying to find amount of NULL values for a column returning 0?

Tags: mysql, null, myisam

I have a column in my table that has a few different values, of which I verified by using a `group by`.

When I do something like this it returns a number amount:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE age='';
```

However when I do this it always returns `0` even though that is incorrect:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE age=NULL;
```

Any idea why this is returning 0 when it should be returning the correct result?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE age IS NULL;
```

Read [3.3.4.6. Working with NULL Values](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/working-with-null.html)

> To test for NULL, you cannot use the
>   arithmetic comparison operators such
>   as =, <, or <>.
>
> Use the IS NULL
>   and IS NOT NULL operators instead:

Comment: In short, NULL is a special value which by definition cannot ever be equal to anything else, including itself.

Answer (score 1):

NULL represents an *unknown* value, so NULL isn't technically equal to anything - **including itself**.

You should use `IS NULL` instead:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE age IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to say "age IS NULL" not "age=null".  NULL is not equal to anything -- it means there is no data and you cannot test for equality.